# Creating conda environment in Docker fails

Tags: docker, pip, conda

I am trying to create a conda environment in Docker, which has worked fine in the past. Recently, however, I am met with the following error

Command
`conda env create --file /workflow/environment.yml`

Error

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '=' (from line 9 of /workflow/condaenv.8c7h85ns.requirements.txt)
Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

This is the contents of my `environment.yml` file

```
name: pipeline
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip=20.2.*
  - snakemake=5.22.*
  - nanoplot=1.31.*
  - nanofilt=2.7.*
  - nanoqc=0.9.*
  - minimap2=2.*
  - seqkit=0.13.*
  - cutadapt=2.*
  - plotly=4.8.*
  - spoa=4.*
  - seaborn=0.10.*
  - edlib>=1.1.2
  - natsort=7.1.*
  - pip:
        - networkx==2.3.*
```

The only place I'm using pip is in the last line, and I'm already using a double equal-sign. I tried to create the environment outside docker, which worked. I'm not sure where this is going wrong.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The only thing strange is the indentation, which could just be the posting here. But generally, make sure the YAML is valid - YAML parsing can be finicky. Mind if I ask why bother with `pip` at all, since `networkx` is available on both `conda-forge` and `defaults` channels?

Comment: @merv Ahh, I wasn't even aware of this. I thought I had checked and couldn't find it. I don't see why this would not work for me. Thanks!